# How to add multiple data from a TextInput on one screen and use it on another with kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, store, textinput

I am currently creating an app with kivy language that shall fit for IOS. On one screen i want to gather data from TextInput, for example "company names" that the reader is typing in. On the next screen i want to show all the collected data. Anyone knows a smooth way to do so? I've read about JsonStore, but i've never got it to work. All attributions are welcome! :)

Comment: have you taking a look at sqlite??

Comment: You can "just do it", i.e. read the content of the textinput to a variable and put the variable into any widget for the next screen.

Comment: I see, would that be possible with more than just one data? Since if i am creating an variable, i can only save one input data to that specific variable? @syntonym

Comment: I cant say that i've. I'll give it a look :) @droptop

Comment: @STR You can also use a list or a dictionary as a variable. Do you have some example code of your first and second screen? It is easier to help with some concrete code.